# Can I take my spearfishing gun and free-diving equipment on a Cathay Pacific flight?

Tags: luggage, legal, cathay-pacific, fishing, sport-equipment

I'm flying from Italy to Australia with Cathay Pacific. Can I take my spearfishing gun, and other free-diving equipment with me as luggage?

Comment: Might be worth saying which country you're flying *from*, too - they're the country whose airport security will make the actual decision

Comment: http://www.medfish.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3727

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since Cathay is HK ailines and all planes are registered in HK, so they follow HK law.

Based on HK Law (**[Firearms And Ammunition Ordnance](http://www.legislation.gov.hk/blis_pdf.nsf/6799165D2FEE3FA94825755E0033E532/34B108CF0F217C6F482575EE00512A29?OpenDocument&bt=0)**), spearfishing gun is arm. The Sect 2 of the ordinance consider any harpoon or spear gun, however powered or size, as arm. However the law does not rule the ammunition of spearfishing gun.

Base on sect 8, you may take spearfishing gun on CX flight if you stay in  restricted area. However, the items should be put in checked luggage, and also [HK customs may ask you official certificate which you are allowed to own spearfishing gun in both departure and arrival countries.](http://medfish.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3727)

There is no other specific rules related to carry general diving equipment on flight in HK, except gas tank and arms.

Comment: Do I have to pay for extra luggage for the gun and equipment?

Comment: No idea sorry @joernano

Comment: Wanna look that up for some extra 15 rep? :)

Comment: But cathay pretty much on overweight luggage, sometimes even higher than flight fare.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can, but the **spear gun can only be taken in checked-in** luggage.
First, while not a firearm it's a projectile weapon nevertheless, and all airports forbid carrying such on board in carry-on baggage or on person. Second, TSA seems to consider spear guns as sporting goods that can be used as bludgeons.

More info on [TSA website](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/prohibited-items)

Comment: Not sure TSA applies here (as the person is not flying to or from the US) but their rules do sometime set precedence for other countries.